# saving row instead of restoring the data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, grid

I want to save the data instead of restore it when I select another row. How I can accomplish that?

I've been testing with this code without any results:

```
    onSelectRow: function(row_id) { 
        if(row_id && row_id !== last_selected) {
            /*
             * Save row.
             */
            $('#grid').jqGrid('saveRow', ((last_selected !== undefined)?last_selected:row_id) , true, function() {/* OnEditFunction */}, function(response) {
                /* SuccessFunction */
                var row_to_save = ((last_selected !== undefined)?last_selected:row_id);

                success_function(row_to_save, response);

                }, 'http://some_url.com');

            last_selected = row_id;
        }   

        /*
         * Edit row.
         */
        $('grid').jqGrid('editRow', row_id, true, function() {/* OnEditFunction */}, function(response) {
            /* SuccessFunction */
            success_function(row_id, response);

            }, 'http://some_url.com'); 
    },
```

It could be great if I could be able to fire a success function before the row is saved successfully, so I can show a notification message.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you have the problem because one small error in your current implementation of the `succesfunc` which you use in [saveRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#saverow) or [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#editrow). The method [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#editrow) just forward the `succesfunc` parameter to [saveRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#saverow), so you will find the detailed description of the `succesfunc` parameter in the documentation of the [saveRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#saverow). You can read the following:

> succesfunc: if defined, this function is called immediately after the
>   request is successful. This function is passed the data returned from
>   the server. Depending on the data from server; this function should
>   return true or false.

So you should at least **include `return true;` as the last statement of your implementation of the `succesfunc`**.

Comment: Yes, I'm returning true or false in the inner `success_function`. Can you show me a working example with `saveRow` and `editRow`?

Comment: @diosney: you should change you code to use `function(response) { return success_function(row_id, response); }`. Currently the value returned by `success_function` will be not forward.

Comment: Great! That make sense. After several attempts I managed to bring to work the code by replacing `((last_selected !== undefined)?last_selected:row_id)` by `last_selected`, removing `var row_to_save = ((last_selected !== undefined)?last_selected:row_id);`
 and changing `row_to_save` parameter in `success_function` to `last_selected` and last but most important: I followed your advice and placed the return stament as you tell me.

Comment: @diosney: I am glad to hear (to read) that your problem is solved and I could help you. You are welcome!